# Does this set with this operation define a group?

Tags: group-theory

Consider the set $A = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n,e\}$. Here, $e$ will be our identity. Define the operation * such that $a_i*a_j = e$ for all $i,j\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $k*e = e*k = k$ for all $k\in A$. Is this a group?

I feel that it satisfies all three properties: associativity, existence of an identity, existence of an inverse for each element. However, clearly the inverses here are not unique... which goes against the easily derivable fact that inverses *are* unique in groups. What's going on intuitively here?

EDIT: Oh wow, it's not associative, thanks guys.

Comment: It is non-associative if the $a_i$s are unique.

Comment: It seems to me we don't have associativity : $(a_1 * a_2) * a_3 = e * a_3 = a_3$ while $a_1 * (a_2 * a_3) = a_1 * e = a_1$.

Comment: The equation $k*e=e*k=e$ defines an *absorption* element, not an identity element. (Contrast the numbers $0$ and $1$ with respect to multiplication.) Did you mean $k*e=e*k=\color{Red}{k}$? John and Joel's comments and Nitrogen's answer are based on the latter interpretation. If you intended the first, then your operation is associative but has no identity element.

Comment: As you've defined it, it looks like you've set $a*b=e$ for all $a,b\in A$. This isn't a group either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is associativity. Indeed, you have $$a_i=a_i*(a_j*a_k)\ne (a_i*a_j)*a_k=a_k$$ unless $a_i=a_k$ for every $i,k$, i.e., there is at most one non trivial element $a$. So $A=\{e,a\}$ which is of course isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/2$.

Edit: As whacka pointed out, I assumed that you meant $k*e=e*k=k$, otherwise it is obvious that $A=\{e\}$.

Comment: The presence of an absorption element $e$ does not imply $A=\{e\}$. Indeed, the multiplication table originally given would be $(n\Bbb Z/n^2\Bbb Z,\times)$ under multiplication.  (Of course, if we further assumed $A$ was a group, *that* would force $A=\{e\}$.)

Comment: Of course, I assumed that he really wanted $A$ to be a group, so I gave the conditions for this to happen.